# Create new HTML elements based on JSON data - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to create dynamic html elements based on JSON data. Created a controller to fetch data. created checkbox based on type with title from contents array. But now i need to create text box when i click on third(Alien) checkbox based on onSelection array.Any idea how to do it will be helpful

```
app.controller('ContentCtrll', function (MedService) {
var ctrll = this;
ctrll.content = [];
ctrll.fetchContent = function () {
    MedService.getMeds().then(function (result) {
        ctrll.content = result.data.book.contents;
    });
};
ctrll.fetchContent();
});
```

JSON

```
"book" : {

    "title" : "Action",
    "contents" : [
        {
            "title" : "Terminator",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Predator",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Alien",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
            "onSelection" : [
                {
                    "title" : "Total copies",
                    "type" : "TEXT"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Sold copies",
                    "type" : "TEXT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "Batman",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
            "onSelection" : [
                {
                    "title" : "",
                    "type" : "TEXT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what it was about, but do i clearly understand - you wnat to put text box after some kind of click on third checkbox based on onSelection array.
You can add a `ng-if=""`  statement, which checks if `onSelection` exist.
Here is html table, in which I listed all your json datas :

```
<table>
     <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Book</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat-start="n in data">
        <td>
        <button ng-if="n.expanded_param" type="button" ng-click="expand_param(n);">-</button>
        <button ng-if="!n.expanded_param" type="button"  ng-click="expand_param(n);">+</button>
        </td>
       <td>{{n.book.title}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-if="n.expanded_param" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="100%">
             <div>
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="name in n.book.contents" >
                     {{name.title}}    <br />
                     {{name.type}}    
                      <ul ng-if="name.onSelection">
                        <li ng-repeat="onSelection in name.onSelection">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="type text"/>
                           {{onSelection.title}} <br />
                           {{onSelection.type}}
                        </li>
                  </ul>
                  </li>
                  </ul>

                                        </div>
            </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And i put `input` only under the `onSelection`
Here is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1nUm8f1tLMScsWkbc8Ko?p=preview